# Equivalent of joda.ISODateTimeFormat in java.time?

Tags: java, jodatime, java-time

I have the following joda date parser:

`ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().withOffsetParsed()`.

I'd like to refactor this to `java.time` api. But what is the exact equivalent to the parser above, especially regarding the offset?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **best equivalent** should be this constant in package `java.time.format` which prefers the parsed offset according to the documentation (like the behaviour when Joda-withOffsetParsed() is used):

[DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME)

However, there are still **small differences**. The decimal separator must be a dot in Java-8 (comma not tolerated although valid and even recommended in ISO-paper). Also: Java-8 manages nanosecond precision in contrast to Jodas millisecond precision. And maybe most important difference: If the offset is missing in your input then Java-8 throws an exception but Joda not (and applies the default time zone).

About choice of type: Since you are working with `DateTime` and fixed offsets the best equivalent should be here `OffsetDateTime` in Java-8. Example of migration:

```
DateTime dt = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime(input);
```

=>

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(input, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is an exact equivalent for this. However you can use [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class to construct the dates as per the required pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The best I've found given my constraints was to use two `DateTimeFormatter` one for parsing (based on suggestion of [DateTimeFormatter Accepting Multiple Dates and Converting to One (java.time library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600420/datetimeformatter-accepting-multiple-dates-and-converting-to-one-java-time-libr)) and one for formatting:

```java
@DataProvider
public static Object[][] dates() {
    return new Object[][] {
            { "2021-02-23T01:42:01.000-0000" },
            { "2021-02-23T01:42:01.000+0000" },
            { "2021-02-23T16:00:00.000-0800" },
            { "2021-02-23T05:42:00.000+0530" },
            { "2021-02-23T00:00:00.0Z" }
    };
}

@Test(dataProvider = "dates")
public void testFormatter(String date) {
    final DateTime jodaTime = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime(date);
    final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatterForParsing =
            new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive()
                                          .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.[SSSX][SX]")
                                          .toFormatter();
    final ZonedDateTime jdkTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(date, dateTimeFormatterForParsing);
    // see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44600420/datetimeformatter-accepting-multiple-dates-and-converting-to-one-java-time-libr
    System.out.println(jodaTime + " vs " + jdkTime.format(dateTimeFormatterForParsing));

    final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatterForFormatting =
            new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().parseCaseInsensitive()
                                          .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX")
                                          .toFormatter();
    assertThat(jodaTime.toString()).isEqualTo(jdkTime.format(dateTimeFormatterForFormatting));
}
```

You can't use the same formatter for parsing and formatting because the above formatter used for parsing would output `2021-02-23T16:42:00.000-080-08` for `2021-02-23T16:42:00.000-0800`.

That feels a bit hackish, though.