# DateTimeFormatter Accepting Multiple Dates and Converting to One (java.time library)

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format, java-time, datetime-parsing

I am trying to write a `DateTimeFormatter` that will allow me to take in multiple different `String` formats, and then convert the `String` formats to a specific type. Due to the scope of the project and the code that already exists, I cannot use a different type of formatter.

E.g., I want to accept `MM/dd/yyyy` as well as `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` but then when I print I only want to print to `MM/dd/yyyy` format and have it in the format when I call `LocalDate.format(formatter);`

Could someone suggest ideas on how to do this with the `java.time.format.*;`

Here is how I could do it in `org.joda`:

```
// MM/dd/yyyy format
DateTimeFormatter monthDayYear = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
// array of parsers, with all possible input patterns
DateTimeParser[] parsers = {
        // parser for MM/dd/yyyy format
        monthDayYear.getParser(),
        // parser for yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss format
        DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").getParser()
};
DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // use the monthDayYear formatter for output (monthDayYear.getPrinter())
    // and parsers array for input (parsers)
    .append(monthDayYear.getPrinter(), parsers)
    // create formatter (using UTC to avoid DST problems)
    .toFormatter()
    .withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

I have not found a good/working example of this online.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I've tested this with **JDK 1.8.0_131 for Mac OS X** and **JDK 1.8.0111 for Windows** (both worked).

I've created a `DateTimeFormatter` with optional sections (delimited by `[]`), to parse both cases (`MM/dd/yyyy` and `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss`).

The same formatter worked for your case (`LocalDate`), but there are some considerations below.

```
// parse both formats (use optional section, delimited by [])
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("[MM/dd/yyyy][yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss]");

// parse MM/dd/yyyy
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.parse("10/16/2016", parser);
// parse yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.parse("2016-10-16T10:20:30", parser);

// parser.format(d1) is the same as d1.format(parser)
System.out.println(parser.format(d1));
System.out.println(parser.format(d2));
```

The output is:

> 10/16/2016
>   10/16/2016

---

**PS:** this works only with `LocalDate`. If I try to format an object with time fields (like `LocalDateTime`), both formats are used:

```
System.out.println(parser.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

This prints:

> 06/18/20172017-06-18T07:40:55

Note that it formatted with both patterns. My guess is that the formatter checks if the object has the fields in each optional section. As the `LocalDate` has no time fields (hour/minute/second), the second pattern fails and it prints only the first one (`MM/dd/yyyy`). But the `LocalDateTime` has all the time fields, and both patterns are valid, so both are used to format.

My conclusion is: this isn't a general solution (like the Joda-Time's version), it's more like a "lucky" case where the patterns involved created the desired situation. But I wouldn't rely on that for all cases.

Anyway, if you are only using `LocalDate`, you can try to use this code. But if you're working with another types, then you'll probably have to use **another** formatter for the output, like this:

```
// parser/formatter for month/day/year
DateTimeFormatter mdy = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
// parser for both patterns
DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // optional MM/dd/yyyy
    .appendOptional(mdy)
    // optional yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss (use built-in formatter)
    .appendOptional(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
    // create formatter
    .toFormatter();

// parse MM/dd/yyyy
LocalDate d1 = LocalDate.parse("10/16/2016", parser);
// parse yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss
LocalDate d2 = LocalDate.parse("2016-10-16T10:20:30", parser);

// use mdy to format
System.out.println(mdy.format(d1));
System.out.println(mdy.format(d2));

// format object with time fields: using mdy formatter to avoid multiple pattern problem
System.out.println(mdy.format(LocalDateTime.now()));
```

The output is:

> 10/16/2016
>   10/16/2016
>   06/18/2017

Comment: Tanks! The one that should be at the top

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking is not possible.

`DateTimeFormatter` is a `final` class, so you cannot subclass it to implement your own behavior.

The constructor is package-private, so you can't call it yourself. The only way to create a `DateTimeFormatter` is by using a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`. Note that the `static` helper methods for creating a `DateTimeFormatter` are internally using `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, e.g.

```
public static DateTimeFormatter ofPattern(String pattern) {
    return new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern(pattern).toFormatter();
}
```

`DateTimeFormatterBuilder` is also a `final` class, and cannot be subclassed, and it doesn't provide any methods for supplying multiple alternate formats to use, like you want.

In short, `DateTimeFormatter` is closed and cannot be extended. If your code can only use a `DateTimeFormatter`, then you are out of luck.

Comment: I want to be able to allow multiple different types of input.. I know for the org.joda I can do this what I listed above.

Comment: I know it's for sure possible in org.joda.. is the java library just directly inferior and less useful than the joda one?

Comment: @AlexKornhauser It is neither inferior nor less useful than Joda-Time. It's just slightly different. I believe some of the people that wrote Joda-Time was part of the group writing the `java.time` classes, applying lessons learned from Joda-Time, which means it's actually *better* than Joda-Time. The Joda-Time [website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) even encourages people to switch from Joda-Time to `java.time`: *Joda-Time is the de facto standard date and time library for Java prior to Java SE 8. **Users are now asked to migrate to `java.time`** (JSR-310).*

Answer (score 2):

The [Answer by Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44600889/642706) is correct and should be accepted.

## Check length of string

As an alternative, you can simply test the length of your string and apply one of two formatters.

```
DateTimeFormatter fDateOnly = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MM/dd/uuuu" ) ;
DateTimeFormatter fDateTime = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME ;

LocalDate ld = null ;
if( input.length() == 10 ) {
    try {
        ld = LocalDate.parse( input , fDateOnly ) ;
    } catch (DateTimeParseException  e ) {
        …
    }
} else if ( input.length() == 19 ) {
    try {
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , fDateTime ) ;
        ld = ldt.toLocalDate() ;
    } catch (DateTimeParseException  e ) {
        …
    }
} else {
    // Received unexpected input.
    …
}

String output = ld.format( fDateOnly ) ;
```

Be aware that you can let java.time automatically localize when generating a string representing the value of your date-time rather than hard-code a specific format. See [DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ofLocalizedDate-java.time.format.FormatStyle-).

Answer (score 2):

The parsing part can be written, and has been added in the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library. The relevant code is [here](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra/blob/master/src/main/java/org/threeten/extra/Temporals.java#L160) and is included below for clarity. The key trick is using `parseUnresolved()` to find out which format is correct:

```
public static <T> T parseFirstMatching(CharSequence text, TemporalQuery<T> query, DateTimeFormatter... formatters) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(text, "text");
    Objects.requireNonNull(query, "query");
    Objects.requireNonNull(formatters, "formatters");
    if (formatters.length == 0) {
        throw new DateTimeParseException("No formatters specified", text, 0);
    }
    if (formatters.length == 1) {
        return formatters[0].parse(text, query);
    }
    for (DateTimeFormatter formatter : formatters) {
        try {
            ParsePosition pp = new ParsePosition(0);
            formatter.parseUnresolved(text, pp);
            int len = text.length();
            if (pp.getErrorIndex() == -1 && pp.getIndex() == len) {
                return formatter.parse(text, query);
            }
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            // should not happen, but ignore if it does
        }
    }
    throw new DateTimeParseException("Text '" + text + "' could not be parsed", text, 0);
}
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to write a single `DateTimeFormatter` that supports flexible parsing and prints using a specific output format as per Joda-Time.